# Tic Tac Toe Program

Tags: javafx

I have this TicTacToe game and instructor wanted us to make it a WILD tic tac toe. So the user needs to be able to select if they want to be X or O whenever. I am unsure of how to do this. I have the buttons but I just need to assign them to the actions, can someone please help me out and how can I make them play again? Here is the TicTacToe class. Thank you in advance.

```html
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.application.Platform;

public class TicTacToe extends Application {

  private char whoseTurn = 'X';

  private Cell[][] cell =  new Cell[3][3];

  private Label lblStatus = new Label("X's turn to play");

  @Override 
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      
     Button xButton = new Button("X");
     Button oButton = new Button("O");
     Button exit = new Button("Exit");
     Button play = new Button("Play Again?");
     xButton.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 15pt;");
     oButton.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 15pt;");
     exit.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 15pt;");
     play.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 15pt;");
     
     exit.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
     {
         @Override 
         public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
             Platform.exit();
            }
        });
     
    GridPane pane = new GridPane(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        pane.add(cell[i][j] = new Cell(), j, i);

    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    borderPane.setCenter(pane);
    borderPane.setBottom(lblStatus);
    
    HBox buttonBar = new HBox();
    buttonBar.setSpacing(87.0);
    buttonBar.getChildren().addAll(xButton, oButton, play,exit);

    borderPane.setTop(buttonBar);
   
    
    Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 550, 470);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Wild TicTacToe"); 
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); 
    primaryStage.show();    
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    

  }

  /** Determine if the cell are all occupied */
  public boolean isFull() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        if (cell[i][j].getToken() == ' ')
          return false;

    return true;
  }

  /** Determine if the player with the specified token wins */
  public boolean isWon(char token) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      if (cell[i][0].getToken() == token
          && cell[i][1].getToken() == token
          && cell[i][2].getToken() == token) {
        return true;
      }

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      if (cell[0][j].getToken() ==  token
          && cell[1][j].getToken() == token
          && cell[2][j].getToken() == token) {
        return true;
      }

    if (cell[0][0].getToken() == token 
        && cell[1][1].getToken() == token        
        && cell[2][2].getToken() == token) {
      return true;
    }

    if (cell[0][2].getToken() == token
        && cell[1][1].getToken() == token
        && cell[2][0].getToken() == token) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  
  public class Cell extends Pane {
    
    private char token = ' ';

    public Cell() {
      setStyle("-fx-border-color: black"); 
      this.setPrefSize(2000, 2000);
      this.setOnMouseClicked(e -> handleMouseClick());
    }

    /** Return token */
    public char getToken() {
      return token;
    }

    /** Set a new token */
    public void setToken(char c) {
      token = c;
      
      if (token == 'X') {
        Line line1 = new Line(10, 10, 
          this.getWidth() - 10, this.getHeight() - 10);
        line1.endXProperty().bind(this.widthProperty().subtract(10));
        line1.endYProperty().bind(this.heightProperty().subtract(10));
        Line line2 = new Line(10, this.getHeight() - 10, 
          this.getWidth() - 10, 10);
        line2.startYProperty().bind(
          this.heightProperty().subtract(10));
        line2.endXProperty().bind(this.widthProperty().subtract(10));
        
        // Add the lines to the pane
        this.getChildren().addAll(line1, line2); 
      }
      else if (token == 'O') {
        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse(this.getWidth() / 2, 
          this.getHeight() / 2, this.getWidth() / 2 - 10, 
          this.getHeight() / 2 - 10);
        ellipse.centerXProperty().bind(
          this.widthProperty().divide(2));
        ellipse.centerYProperty().bind(
            this.heightProperty().divide(2));
        ellipse.radiusXProperty().bind(
            this.widthProperty().divide(2).subtract(10));        
        ellipse.radiusYProperty().bind(
            this.heightProperty().divide(2).subtract(10));   
        ellipse.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        ellipse.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        
        getChildren().add(ellipse); // Add the ellipse to the pane
      }
    }

    /* Handle a mouse click event */
    private void handleMouseClick() {
      // If cell is empty and game is not over
      if (token == ' ' && whoseTurn != ' ') {
        setToken(whoseTurn); // Set token in the cell

        // Check game status
        if (isWon(whoseTurn)) {
          lblStatus.setText(whoseTurn + " won! The game is over. Would you like to play again?");
          whoseTurn = ' '; // Game is over
        }
        else if (isFull()) {
          lblStatus.setText("Draw! The game is over. Would you like to play again?");
          whoseTurn = ' '; // Game is over
        }
        else {
          // Change the turn
          whoseTurn = (whoseTurn == 'X') ? 'O' : 'X';
          // Display whose turn
          lblStatus.setText(whoseTurn + "'s turn.");
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  /**
   * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited
   * JavaFX support. Not needed for running from the command line.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is allow the player to choose their piece (`x` or `o`), probably the *easiest* way to do it is to decouple the presentation from the use of the pieces.

By that, I mean have the player represented within the program as the integer `1` and the computer as `0`. This never changes and your logic uses these values.

When displaying the board however, you translate that value into the correct form.

So, two things. First, allow the user to choose their pieces (psuedo-code):

```
def piece as array[2]
COMPUTER = 0
PLAYER   = 1
if playerWantsToBeX:
    piece[COMPUTER] = 'O'
    piece[PLAYER]   = 'X'
else:
    piece[COMPUTER] = 'X'
    piece[PLAYER]   = 'O'
```

Then, when presenting the board, use those values. Whereas before you would have had something like:

```
    print cell[x,y]
```

now you would have:

```
    print piece[cell[x,y]]
```

Comment: How do i add this to the buttons that i created though?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha, by not calling them `xButton/oButton` for a start. Instead call them `playerButton/computerButton` or `firstButton/secondButton` and using the same logic to create a button: `playerButton = new Button(piece[PLAYER])` (a weird mixture of JavaFX and pseudo-code but you should get the idea).

Comment: Yeah I am not understanding it at all, can you possibly add it into my code for me because I just don't know how to do it I suck at java. I cant just use MouseEvent to make the person select X or O?

Comment: @Itachi, since this is almost certainly classwork of some description, just "adding it to your code" will not do you or the industry any favours. I suggest you at least *try* and then come back with a more targeted question.